# Qt reading from QTextStream

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to read a text file and display the contents in a QPlainTextEdit. Please can you point out what I'm doing wrong:

```
QFile jsonFile("data.json");  

if (!jsonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    qDebug() << "Failed to open file";
    qDebug() << jsonFile.errorString();
    return;
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "File opened";
} //It returns that the file opened successfully

qDebug() << "File Exists?: " << jsonFile.exists(); //Yep, it exists.

QTextStream outStream(&jsonFile);
QString textString = outStream.readAll();
qDebug() << "Text string: " << textString; //textString is empty! ""
ui->fileToPost->setPlainText(textString); //fileToPost is the QPlainTextEdit
jsonFile.close();
```

If I do something like

```
QString textString = "The cat sat on the mat";
```

it displays fine. The problem is that nothing is being read from the stream (or maybe the file).

Comment: How large is the file you're reading? "Avoid this function when working on large files, as it will consume a significant amount of memory.
Calling readLine() is better if you do not know how much data is available."
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtextstream.html#readAll

Comment: +1, I think that the content does not display wit `qDebug()` in case of large files.
Otherwise, you are testing `jsonFile.exists()` after having opened it. Are you sure that the data.json file is in the path? You should do the `jsonFile.exists()` before opening it.

Comment: You cannot open a file if it doesn't exist. But really, the check of existence is unnecessery, or you should do it before you try to open the file.

Comment: otisonoza/ Sylvain: The file is small - maybe 15 lines max. It is just a "fake" file I created to test this function. I am hoping file length will not be an issue.

Comment: Try removing the check where you check if you've opened it succesfully. I remember that I used the same example as in http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qfile.html , and I had to modify the conditions. Just simply open it.

Comment: and what will result `qDebug()<<QString(jsonFile.readAll());` right after you have opened the file?

Comment: I tried removing the IF, leaving just the line
   jsonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
With no checking. No difference. textString is still blank.

Comment: Shf: Interesting test. I get the empty string: ""  
What should I infer from that? The file is not empty, so is it not being read?

Comment: Maybe something's wrong with the parameters you pass by open(...).
Try to open it as simply as possible. Sylvain may be right. Is data.json in the right place? I had strange issues and I had to change the conditions to the opposite.

Comment: @Dirk it is just another way to read file to QString, without QTextStream (maybe there was trouble). It means, that file is indeed cannot be read for some reason. Check if file exists: `qDebug()<<QFileInfo("data.json").exists();`

Comment: @Shf: It returns true.

Comment: @otisonoza: I wondered about that too. But it says it opened it successfully, and AFAIK it will not create it if it does not exist already. I'm stumped.

Comment: You can try to create a new file (different name), and see if it's in the same plase as the data.json. If not, the file is in the wrong place.

Comment: Try excluding some possible error cases: Put a temporary file somewhere and try opening that with an absolute path to see if your code works. If it works, try with a relative path on the same file. Another option is to try an absolute path on your json.data file.

Comment: @Dirk i'm almost at loss, it exist and it is indeed empty. Last check - if it returns the file path, you expect:`qDebug()<<QFileInfo("data.json").absoluteFilePath()`

Comment: @Shf: Just tried that. I think we have paydirt. It returns:
C:/Users/.../QtCode/build-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/data.json
   .... which is not the place I thought it was. So I will explore that now. Thanks!

Comment: @Dirk glad, that it solved your problem, posted solution as answer

Comment: @Shf: Well .... not finished yet. It opened the file, and the qDebug read it, but textString is still empty. Do you know why?

Comment: @Dirk i think, it just have created empty file in that absolute path

Comment: Fixed that. ... needed to comment out the qDebug, of course. 

Hmm - did not know if would create the file if it did not exists. An interesting learning experience overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check file's absolute path, probably it is not where, you expect it: `qDebug()<<QFileInfo("data.json").absoluteFilePath();`